# How do you update Task Labels?

Tags: podio

I need to update Task labels.
I get the task, I can step through the PodioCollection of labels ($task->labels)
I remove a label
    $this->labels->remove($labelToRemove->label_id);
I add a label

```
$newLabel = new PodioTaskLabel();
$newLabel->text = $labelText;
$task->labels[] = $newLabel;
```

I then save the $task
    $task->save();

The $task is saved, but the updated Task Labels are not.

The documentation here makes no sense:
https://developers.podio.com/doc/tasks/update-task-labels-151769

It says "Updates the task with new labels" at the top.
It  also says you call it with:
    /task/{task_id}/label/

But you call it with:

```
PodioTaskLabel::update( $label_id, $attributes = array() );
```

Huh? Why does it say in one place it is called with {task_id} but then down below, say it is called with $label_id.

In the PHP code it links to, it has this:

```
return Podio::put("/task/label/{$label_id}", $attributes);
```

Which causes me to believe the documentation is wrong.

Where in that ::update() call do I pass the task_id of the Task I want to update?

Or is there some *other* way to update task labels that is just undocumented?

-- Andrew.

Comment: I attempted to "reverse engineer" this (as I have had to do with much of Podio's undocumented API) but as is so common, Podio doesn't use the end-user provided API for their app, so Podio uses /_json/tasks/<taskid>.json when they update, which isn't helpful since I'm not allowed to use that API.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in php client. Same code for **Ruby** works just great:

```
Podio::Task.update_labels(task_id, ['test label'])
```

Feel free to fix php client and submit pull request with fix.